# JavaScript Object vs Map - how to handle special keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, dictionary

In Java, I find it straight forward to take a string and use it as a key in a `LinkedHashMap`. I can even translate it into JSON and back with no troubles.

I am using Node.JS/JavaScript now, and there is a special case that is not handled.

```
var makesSense = '{"__proto__":"foo","toString":"bar"}'
var noSense = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('{"__proto__":"foo","toString":"bar"}'))
console.log(noSense) // outputs {"toString":"bar"}
```

What is the recommended way to handle `__proto__` and other things like it. It would seem that `toString` is not causing any trouble, but supposing I needed consistent handling of untrusted data. What is the recommended solution?

- Prepend an extra character before every key? If so, what character makes the most sense? I know it can't be an underscore, so what about a space?
- Use a module that handles this for me? I would want one that will handle this conveniently and without excessive features. (some features would be nice though)
- Something else? Is there a solution that is compatible with `JSON.parse`?

Why does this matter? Surely nobody is actually going to type `__proto__` by accident. But what if they were doing this on purpose. They learn I am using JavaScript, so what? - No problems except in the following situation:

- Software has a array of strings. It just so happens one of these strings say `__proto__` because someone was poking around trying to break my software.
- Software creates a Map using those strings for a key, and fills the Map with some nice data.
- Software later goes through the array of strings, and collects the information from the Map. The Map returns something null, and then *boom*: null pointer exception.
- Software now does not work. This would qualify as something sort of like denial of service.

I know that that situation is absolutely vary rare, but I don't like it. I cannot remember all the quirks of the programming language I am using, so given enough time, I am bound to write this kind of code.

I pride myself on creating code that is not subject to tampering. So, I am attempting to eliminate these pinholes from my software.

Yes, these are super-minor, but it is at least worth a StackOverflow question, to see if people have a better answer than I know. I learn a lot this way.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? It seems **really** unlikely to me that you'd have a real-world situation where you were getting JSON with keys like `__proto__` and `toString`.

Comment: Btw, the above snippet has the correct output in Opera.

Comment: You could try to patch your Node.js installation and just disable the `__proto__` quirks :-)

Comment: I posted an issue report [on V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2532), as well as on [Node.JS](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4728).

Comment: @Bergi, I'd love to know how. I would probably just disable it for a `Map` object. That way, I would not end up breaking all the other objects.

Comment: Another Opera test: Objects without a protoype (e.g. `Object.create(null)`) will allow assigning and retrieving the `__proto__` property without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Prepend an extra character before every key? If so, what character makes the most sense? I know it can't be an underscore, so what about a space?

I use an `x`, but it's arbitrary. So long as you use something that's unlikely to form a special property name like (on some engines) `__proto__`, or `toString`, or `valueOf` (and I'm not aware of any special property names starting with `x`), you're fine.